# cucumber ruby rescue exception Scenario name

Tags: ruby, exception, cucumber, capybara

I'm writing some tests that use Cucumbers data table.  It iterates through 11 scenarios and if there is a failure on line 1, the following get ignored (as we know).  The powers that be would like me to add some exception handling to this so that the whole table is checked regardless. Here is my table:

```
 | Row | add_line_1    | add_line_2 | add_line_3     | post_town | post_code | error                                                                                                                              |
      | 1   | 123           | Over There | And down a bit | Swansea   | SA9 2NG   | Building/number and street must contain between 4 and 30 farts                                                                |
      | 2   | 1234          | Over There | And down a bit | Swansea   | SA9 2NG   | Must have at least 3 alpha characters                                                                                              |
      | 3   | ****          | Over There | And down a bit | Swansea   | SA9 2BG   | The first character of the address must be alphanumeric. Other characters must be valid (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, &, -, (), /, ' and , or .) |
      | 4   | ***           | Over There | And down a bit | Swansea   | SA9 2BG   | Building/number and street must contain between 4 and 30 characters                                                                |
      | 5   | 1 High Street | ***        | And down a bit | Swansea   | SA9 2BG   | The first character of the address must be alphanumeric. Other characters must be valid (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, &, -, (), /, ' and , or .) |
      | 6   | 1 High Street | Over There | ***            | Swansea   | SA9 2BG   | The first character of the address must be alphanumeric. Other characters must be valid (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, &, -, (), /, ' and , or .) |
      | 7   | 1 High Street | Over There | And down a bit | ****      | SA9 2BG   | Post town contains invalid characters                                                                                              |
      | 8   | 1 High Street | Over There | And down a bit | ***       | SA9 2BG   | Post town contains invalid characters                                                                                              |
      | 9   | 1 High Street | Over There | And down a bit | A         | SA9 2BG   | Post town requires a minimum length of three characters                                                                            |
      | 10  | 1 High Street | Over There | And down a bit | Swansea   | ***       | Must be between five and eight characters and in a valid format, e.g. AB1 2BA or AB12BA
```

The test usually fails on line one as the expected error text is incorrect.

So I have written this into my code:

```
begin
    expect(all_text).to have_text @error
rescue Exception => e
  puts "#{scenario.name} >>"
  puts "Table row #{@row}: #{e}"
end
```

On it's own the exception handling doesn't tell you much about where the failure has occurred if you consider there are 40+ tables throughout the test pack.

I wanted to capture the scenario name and have that included in the exception handling but I get an error saying undefined method for scenario.

Is there a way I could add that to the block of code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The more I have read, the more I realised this couldn't be done the way I wanted.  So I did the following:

```
Before do |scenario|
  @feature_name = scenario.feature.name
  @scenario_name = scenario.name
end

begin
  expect(all_text).to have_text @error
  rescue Exception => e
  puts @feature_name + ' : ' + @scenario_name
  puts "Table row #{@row}: #{e}"
end
```

Comment: If you don't want it to raise an exception, don't use expect.  if all_text_ is an element use `has_text?` on it instead, and if it's a string just use ==, with if